# Redirect stderr from a script WITH command that generated the error

Tags: bash

I have a bash script calling multiple commands.
I have redirected all error output using

```
    exec 2> logfile
```

While this works, it would be nice to get the command that generated the error input to the logfile.
Anyone got a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be useful to you?:

```
BASH_XTRACEFD="2"
set -x
```

Comment: I am familiar with set -x and have used it for debugging, but I am not familiar with the variable you are setting
When I add this to my script, all commands that are run are output to the logfile, I would like to simply get only those commands that generate an error

Comment: I guess one way to do this would be to process the output with sed: `sed -e '/^+/{h;d};:a;H;N;s/.*\n//;/^+/{x;p;d};ba' logfile`.

Comment: I appreciate the input, and while this does accomplish what I asked I am not sure how I feel about having the script run in debug all the time. I'll credit your answer, but I think I'm going to live with what I get just using exec 2> logfile